# Rails 4 page reload after ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an application that displays a large number of informational pages based on a location that I store in the session variable.

I am using a single select in a partial shared between varied pages from other controllers.

_location_select.html.erb

```
<%= select_tag(:location, options_for_select(Location.all.order('name ASC').collect { |l| [l.name, l.id] }, [session[:location]||'']), include_blank: true) %>
```

This makes an ajax call to:

locations_controller.rb

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def select
    session[:location] = params[:value]
    render js: ''
  end
end
```

Here is my coffescript:

home.js.coffee

```
$ ->
  $('#location').change ->
    $.get '/location/select', {value: $('option:selected', this).val()}
```

All of this code works great, but I need to have the page reload after the ajax call is complete, It would be too complicated to have the controller return the updated html since the location select will appear on such a large number of pages.

I have tried adding success:, and error: call back functions to the ajax call and have also played around with ajaxStop. I can get the ajax call to work or the page reload to work but cannot figure out the way to get both.

I have tried adding:

```
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
    window.location.reload();
});
```

Where do I put location.reload() or is there a better way?

FYI, I am not using turbolinks in this app.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

locations_controller.rb

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def select
    session[:location] = params[:value]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js   {}
    end
  end
end
```

views/locations/select.js

```
window.location.reload();
```

Comment: So easy and so obvious, I am almost embarrassed to admit, that I did not try that first.

Comment: And at least in rails 4, I don't think the respond_to block is required - if select.js is the only select.* view file in the views/locations folder, it will get picked up automatically

Comment: it so hard to see the forest through the trees sometimes. simple and beautiful.