# Get the id of a created object in rails using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, http-post

I want to get the id of an element that I have created using a query-AJAX-POST-Request, but none of the approaches that I have found so far, had worked.

Currently I am stuck here

Controller:

```
def createuserlink
  @new_element = Link.new(element_params)
  @new_element.save
  respond_with @new_element  
end
```

Jquery:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "links/createuserlink",
    type: "POST",
    data: my_data
  }).done(function( data, textStatus, request ) {
    alert(data);
  });
```

The Request works and the new_element gets created, but the alert-message shows me the HTML-code of the new_element/show page. I can see the id of the returned page in the browser dev-tools (like `foo.com/element/42`), but I don't know how to access it.

I tried to use `getResponseHeader` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557602/jquery-and-ajax-response-header), but it only works for parameters (like `foo.com?element=42`).

I also tried `respond_with @new_element.id`, but he didn't liked the syntax.

What is the easiest and recommended way to get back the id?

Comment: Create createuserlink.js.erb or createuserlink.js.haml file to show your data. Please refer this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18900799/2681997.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like you want json, not a template, instead of respond_with, why not try:

```
def createuserlink
  @new_element = Link.new(element_params)
  @new_element.save
  render json: @new_element.to_json
end
```